# C#/DevExpress Enable/disable one or many checkedcombobox based on a checkedcombobox selection

Tags: c#, devexpress

i'm new to coding and i um stuck in a situation where i need use `DevExpress` in `C#`..and the issue is that i used 2 `checkedcombobox` and once an item is selected in the first `checkedcombobox` i need to enable the other `checkedcombobox` but when it's unticked i need to disable the other `checkedcombobox`.

```
using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository;

namespace UpdateGmtType
{
    [Flags]
    enum types
    {
        BookRequest= 0x01,
        RawPaperRequest = 0x02,
        BoardRequest = 0x04,
    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties.SetFlags(typeof(types));

            removeCombinedFlags(checkedComboBoxEdit1.Properties);

            checkedComboBoxEdit1.SetEditValue(types.BookRequest);
        }

        private void checkedComboBoxEdit1_EditValueChanged(RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit properties)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private void removeCombinedFlags(RepositoryItemCheckedComboBoxEdit ri)
        {
            for (int i = ri.Items.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                Enum val1 = ri.Items[i].Value as Enum;
                for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    Enum val2 = ri.Items[j].Value as Enum;
                    if (val1.HasFlag(val2))
                    {
                        ri.Items.RemoveAt(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }



private void checkedComboBoxEdit2_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(checkedComboBoxEdit1.SelectedText.ToString() == 1)
        {
            checkedComboBoxEdit2.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            checkedComboBoxEdit2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `if(checkedComboBoxEdit1.SelectedText.ToString() == 1)` will always evaluate to false.  1 is an integer, not a string.  Maybe you're looking for `== "1"`?  Also no need to do `ToString()` on a string.

Comment: i did as mentioned  but i didnt get a postive output ...i mean the checkedcombobox did not get enabled or disabled according to the selection